# How do I prepare this text file for nearest neighbor algorithm?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, nearest-neighbor

I want to prepare the text file so I can use k-NN clusstering in python 2.7. I have no idea how to approach this. Can anybody help?

The dataset is here: http://textuploader.com/ayhqc

Columns are separated by commas and rows are separated by newlines. Each column describes one individual patient. The attributes are in rows in the following order: plasma_glucose, bp, test_result, skin_thickness, num_pregnancies, insulin, bmi, pedigree, age.

Comment: You want to get kNN-what? kNN classification? kNN clustering?

Comment: clustering, sorry I left that out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transpose the data first (below) and then you can use an out of the box algo.

```
import numpy as np
f1=open(,'r')
data=np.zeros(100,6) #rows and cols
j=0
for line in f1:
  row=line.split(',')
  for i in range(len(row)):
    x=row[i]
    if x=='positive': x=1
    elif x=='negative': x=-1
    else: x=float(x)
    data[i,j]=x
  j+=1
```